# linux + dialog bin tool

Tags: linux

I used the dialog binary tool to create some msgbox on Linux screen as the following example

```
        dialog –colors –title “test” –msgbox “type <ENTER> 8 50
```

My question how to kill the dialog process in order to clear the screen without dialog BOX
 , there no dialog process , I check with ps –ef , 
I also try to

```
    dialog –clear
```

this isn’t clear the screen and the dialog box still exist

Please advice?

Answer (score 0):

Try `pkill -HUP dialog`.  You should have a dialog process, since dialog is a separate program; on my system I see it with `ps -ef | grep dialog`.  `pkill` will find it and send it a HUP (or other) signal.  You'll have a mess to clean up on the terminal screen, though; try `reset` for that.

Comment: pkill -HUP not really kill the GUI , I already tried it -:(

Comment: It works for me.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

According to dialog man page you should use `clear` shell command if you want to clear the screen after showing the dialog.

So this should do it:

```
dialog --color --title "test" --msgbox "type <ENTER>" 8 50 && clear
```

Or if you are OK with the dialog box cleared but the dialog background color still there after exiting, this is another variation:

```
dialog --color --clear --title "test" --msgbox "type <ENTER>" 8 50
```

Comment: its not kill the GUI , sorry